# Will a mixed-reality application and experience developed for Hololens 2 using Unity work on Oculus Quest as is?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, hololens, mrtk, oculusquest

To allow sales people to meet clients in the COVID19 era without travelling, busienss wants to create a virtual meeting room .
The clients will get Oculus Quest as Hololens is hard to procure right now where as business wants to use Hololens on their end.

Will an application /experience created for Hololens using Unity work as is on Oculus Quest or does it make sense to have the same device on both end?

I am new to this area, so not sure if this question makes sense, but is it something like developing 2 versions of code, one for iOS and one or Android and using something like Xamarin to make the process easy ?

Does Unity have features to make applications compatible between Hololens and Oculus Quest ?

Answer (score 0):

MRTK makes it easy to make multiplatform XR applications.
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithTheMRTK.html

Unity will allow you to run most applications on both Windows on ARM (HoloLens 2) and Android (Quest).

MRTK even has hand tracking support on both platforms.

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/CrossPlatform/OculusQuestMRTK.html